# Totally re render amchart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have Angular 1.4 app with chart with different time intervals, and I load them on demand.

Here is the UI

[image]

Data is correct each time, but TimeInterval (date ranges) didn't change - always start with Jan 05. How to re render totally chart? I'm try everything: remove/add node from DOM, use amChartObject.clear() and etc.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call the chart object's [`validateData()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#validateData) method after you update the chart's data in order for the chart to reparse the new data and redraw itself.

Comment: Hi xorspark ,  Any Idea how to do this in angularJS . I am using this directive https://github.com/GrantMStevens/amCharts-Angular , and want to rerender the chart

Comment: This really should be its own question rather than a comment on an answer in someone else's question - it's not encouraged on SO. That said, since it's a third party directive, so I would defer to asking them on github. A quick search in their issues yielded [this comment](https://github.com/GrantMStevens/amCharts-Angular/issues/67#issuecomment-249912217) that says you need to broadcast the validateNow event. See if that works for you. If it doesn't, ask the maintainer.